# HttpPost method can't be reached, in ASP.Net MVC Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-post

**Abstract:**
I have an Asp.net MVC project, and a console windows app.
I try to have the console app to post a file to the web project through a [HttpPost] method in a controller.
Both my projects are running locally, each one in its own visual studio instance.
My problem is that my [httppost] method is never called.

**Details:**
Here is the code in the web project

```
public class DevController : Controller  
{  
    [HttpPost]  
    public ActionResult UploadStuff(HttpPostedFileBase file)  
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); //This breakpoint is never reached
        return View();
    }
}
```

Here is the code in the console app :

```
static public async void UploadStuff(Stream streamToUploadToWebProject)
{
    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    content.Add(new StreamContent(streamToUploadToWebProject), "WhateverName");
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    string url = @"http://localhost:12345/dev/UploadStuff";
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
}
```

**Notes:**
1) http://localhost:12345/ : This is the url that is displayed in browser when I run my web project.
2) The file that is sent is an unstructured blob.
3) Most related posts I have found are about uploading a json file (like this post), or are about posting a file from a web page (in which case there is a also "Get" method returning a view containing a "upload" button); Both cases are not same as mine.
4) [Edit] HttpClient.PostAsync returns a "404" error.

**My Question:**
What do I do wrong; how should I write the [HttpPost] method, so that it gets called?

Comment: What the error do you have?

Comment: Also what is the routing you have set up? Default routing?

Comment: Your `UploadStuff` method is `async void`. That's bad! See [Async Await Best Practices by Stephen Cleary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming) and [8 Async Await Mistakes You Should Avoid in .NET by Nick Chapsas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQu-eBIIh-w). To fix it, change it to return a Task, then make sure the method that calls it awaits it, and the method that calls that is marked as Async and returns a Task or Task<T> etc, all the way up the call stack.

Comment: @Serge I don't have any error; the problem is that my method is never called when I run my console app program that makes a "post" to the website. See the breakpoint in the controller method, it is not reached (I run my website attached with debugger)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary No particular routing. To confirm it is not a routing issue, I have created a simple "Get" method beside the UploadStuff; it is well called from my console   app when using same kind of route.

Comment: Your method never finishes running for the reason I described in my previous comment.

Comment: @mason OK, I will fix my code, but I have confirmed it is not a syntax problem; in Console App, HttpClient.PostAysnc is called, and returns. I have added an [Update] in my original post to give the result of this method.

Comment: Once you've properly fixed the async void issue, if you're getting a 404 error, then you've probably got a routing issue. You'll need to show your routing configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller try to use [FromBody] attribute before the parameter.

```
[HttpPost]  
public ActionResult UploadStuff([FromBody]HttpPostedFileBase file)
```

Comment: I tried, but unfortunatly same result.